# libxml++2.36: "double free or corruption" if a std::exception is thrown

Tags: c++11, c++14, libxml2

Hy, 
while using the libxml++-2.36-library for my code I found out, that this library produces a "double free or corruption"-error, when exceptions of the basetype std::exception are thrown in the sax-parser-callbacks. (e.g. on_start_document, on_end_document, on_...)

But it behaves normally, this means, that the exception can be catched, if an exception of basetype [xmlpp::exception](https://developer.gnome.org/libxml++/2.36/classxmlpp_1_1exception.html) is thrown.

Interestingly [xmlpp::exception](https://developer.gnome.org/libxml++/2.36/classxmlpp_1_1exception.html) is based on std::exception.

To verify this, I have created a MWE:

```
#include <libxml++/libxml++.h>
#include <iostream>

class xml_parser : public xmlpp::SaxParser {
protected:
    virtual void on_start_document() override;
};

void xml_parser::on_start_document() {
    throw std::runtime_error("test-exception");
    //throw xmlpp::internal_error("test-exception");
}

int main(void) {
    xml_parser parser;
    try {
        parser.parse_memory(
            u8"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n");
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It can be compiled by:

```
g++  main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs libxml++-2.6`  -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Werror -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wconversion -fdiagnostics-color=auto -g -O2 -std=c++11
```

If I execute the file as it is, I get the following output:

```
*** Error in `./main': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000000b35b30 ***
```

If I uncomment the second line and comment the first line of the on_start_document(), I get the following output:

```
Caught exception: test-exception
```

Compiler: g++ 4.9.2
libxml++: 2.6 - 2.36

Is there a way, to get std::exception based exceptions working, without creating special xmlpp::exception-Based Exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that an `_xmlSAXHandler` object is being freed twice, once by `delete` and another by xmlFree().  This can be seen by setting a break point on the appropriate free() standard libc call.  For example, on an Ubuntu 'trusty' machine, I set a breakpoint on `_int_free` and saw that the same pointer was being freed twice:

```
Breakpoint 2, _int_free (av=0x7ffff741f760 , p=0x610b80, 
    have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3814
3814    in malloc.c
(gdb) bt
#0  _int_free (av=0x7ffff741f760 , p=0x610b80, have_lock=0)
    at malloc.c:3814
#1  0x00007ffff6d32a59 in xmlFreeParserCtxt ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
#2  0x00007ffff7bc6be2 in xmlpp::Parser::release_underlying (
    this=this@entry=0x7fffffffdd30) at libxml++/parsers/parser.cc:162
#3  0x00007ffff7bcc665 in xmlpp::SaxParser::release_underlying (
    this=this@entry=0x7fffffffdd30) at libxml++/parsers/saxparser.cc:329
#4  0x00007ffff7bcc68c in xmlpp::SaxParser::~SaxParser (this=0x7fffffffdd30, 
    __in_chrg=) at libxml++/parsers/saxparser.cc:83
#5  0x0000000000401d80 in ~xml_parser (this=0x7fffffffdd30, 
    __in_chrg=) at so31969961_libxmlpp_double_free.cpp:7
#6  main () at so31969961_libxmlpp_double_free.cpp:24

...

Breakpoint 2, _int_free (av=0x7ffff741f760 , p=0x610b80, 
    have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3814
3814    in malloc.c
(gdb) bt
#0  _int_free (av=0x7ffff741f760 , p=0x610b80, have_lock=0)
    at malloc.c:3814
#1  0x00007ffff7bcc69e in ~auto_ptr (this=0x7fffffffdd60, 
    __in_chrg=) at /usr/include/c++/4.8/backward/auto_ptr.h:170
#2  xmlpp::SaxParser::~SaxParser (this=0x7fffffffdd30, 
    __in_chrg=) at libxml++/parsers/saxparser.cc:81
#3  0x0000000000401d80 in ~xml_parser (this=0x7fffffffdd30, 
    __in_chrg=) at so31969961_libxmlpp_double_free.cpp:7
#4  main () at so31969961_libxmlpp_double_free.cpp:24
```

In this case, 0x610b80 corresponds to the `_xmlSAXHandler` object held by the SaxParser in its `sax_handler_` auto_ptr member.  It is first freed by libxml2's xmlFreeParserCtxt() routine.  It is then deleted by the `std::auto_ptr<_xmlSAXHandler>` destructor.

If you look at the source of libxml++'s SaxParser class, in [`saxparser.cc`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml++/tree/libxml++/parsers/saxparser.cc?id=1cf87fa88021df17163d4f16ffc084f7163225f7), you will see that there are several try..catch statements.  However, only `const exception&` is caught.  This `const exception` is not `std::exception` but rather `xmlpp::exception`.

When you throw a `std::runtime_error` in the on_start_document() handler, it is not caught by SaxParserCallback::start_document().  Consequently, as the stack is unwound, the code in SaxParser::parse() that restores the original `_xmlSAXHandler` pointer in the `_xmlParserCtxt` is skipped.

The takeaway from this is that you should only throw exceptions deriving from `xmlpp::exception` within the SaxParser handler methods.

**UPDATE:** https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=753570

**UPDATE2:** Fixed in version 2.39.2.

Comment: Thanks, so this means, that you should be very very careful, when using this library, because everytime you call a function not noexcept in the handlers you should better add a try-catch block before. 

So I think this library is not easy to use. Would you use this library, now you know how it behaves? And should I create a bugreport or do you think it's not worth it.

Comment: @byteunit:  Yes, I would consider using the library in a C++ project that needs to parse XML.  After all, libxml++ is linked to on libxml2's homepage.  Re creating a bug report:  I think that it would be worth filing a bug report.  Looking at [the list of bug reports](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?list_id=54112&product=libxml%2B%2B), this issue does not appear to have been reported.